# Is this just poor error statement or my understanding is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to set up an error message:

```
let error = response.message || 'blah';
```

and I get an error saying message is undefined.

After a lot of debugging found out that response was not defined.
Ideally the error statement should say property "**message**" not found on undefined object "**response**" something like this
Is this a bad error statement or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Normally it sais `Can't read property "message" of undefined`, which is an accurate error message since `response` is undefined meaning you can't read a property from it.

Comment: @joviDeCroock It's not accurate. In JS, if an object is not defined and you're trying to access a property of that object, the error will say can't read the object. For example, try just this single line in a js file--> console.log(response.message). It will and should say response not defined

Comment: Your operation is reading a property from an object, the most effective error is saying that you can't read it because your target for reading it from is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `response.message` like this :

```
let error = (response.message) ? response.message : 'blah';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing about JS. You'll have to separately check for 'undefined' as it is different from NULL values.

For your case this should work :

```
let error = (response.message) && (typeof response.message !== 'undefined') ? response.message : 'blah';
```

Comment: I know this. Read my question once again

Comment: My bad!! Couldn't understand the question at first. I agree with you. I work on React Native and my app sometimes crashes because I try to check the value of attribute of an undefined object(eg. response.message).